# Delete record from DB warehouse after matching it with staging for the last 5 days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a data warehouse and a staging DB. The staging gets a new file everyday on an ftp which gets  loaded on the staging DB. It is then inserted/updated/deleted in the DB warehouse. However, the staging file has only the last 5 days' records, which are on a rolling basis. That is, from 8/8 to 8/13 would be today, but tomorrow the file would have data from 8/9 to 8/14, while the DB warehouse has all the history.

When I use

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
```

it will delete all the records from DBwarehouse which do not match the staging. This would wipe out all the history. I want to control the script to go back only 5 days back and check if it does not match the source. Here is the query:

```
MERGE INTO 
[x].[y].[z] AS Target
USING [a].[y].[z]AS Source
ON target.[PROBLEM_ID] =source.[PROBLEM_ID]

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET 
Target.[CUSTNO] = Source.[CUSTNO],
Target.[SALESID] = Source.[SALESID],
Target.[PCODE] = Source.[PCODE]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT    
       ([CUSTNO]
       ,[SALESID]
       ,[PCODE])
VALUES

       (source.[CUSTNO]
       ,source.[SALESID]
       ,source.[PCODE])

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
THEN DELETE;

;
```

Can I get a constraint on the delete statement to go only 5 days back on the DB warehouse? If yes, please help me with the constraint code.

Comment: Is there a column in the DBWarehouse table that records the last date that each record was updated?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) says that you can add an "AND" clause to "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE".  This would let you do this:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND Your_Date_Field > DateAdd(Day,-5,GetDate())
THEN DELETE;
```

Note that if your dates includes times you might need to truncate the time before you compare the dates.

Comment: thanks david, but I do not have a column on the DBwarehouse or the staging with a date. thought that would work. I dont know if sql server 2008 assigns a date to each modification on the rows in a tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's basically what you want to do. You use a common table expression to build up a more complex set to merge against. You can also do an "and" on when matched and when not matched, but I find it cleaner to start first with a data set built to purpose in a cte.

Peace
Katherine

```
with [merge_helper] ([custno], [salesid], [pcode])
 as (select [source].[id],
            [source].[custno],
            [source].[salesid],
            [source].[pcode]
     from   [a].[y].[z] as [source]
     left join   [x].[y].[z] as [target]
       on [target].[id] = [source].[id]
     union
     select [target].[id],
            [target].[custno],
            [target].[salesid],
            [target].[pcode]
     from   [x].[y].[z] as [target]
     where  [target].[id] not in (select [id]
                                  from   [source]))
merge into [x].[y].[z] as target
using [merge_helper] as source
on target.[id] = source.[id]
when matched then
update set target.[custno] = source.[custno],
           target.[salesid] = source.[salesid],
           target.[pcode] = source.[pcode]
when not matched by target then
    insert ([custno],
        [salesid],
        [pcode])
values (source.[custno],
        source.[salesid],
        source.[pcode])
when not matched by source then
delete;
```